# How to get a JRE for an old version of eclipse?

Tags: java

For school assignments we need to use eclipse 3.6.  I downloaded it but now can't find a suitable JRE for it.  It says I should use JavaSE-1.6, but it is not
[here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html)

Anyone know where I can find this, or if another JRE version will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRE 1.6 is the same as JRE 6

At version 1.5 they starting naming them version 5, 6, 7 etc.

So on that site download Java SE 6

Link for the latest version of JRE 6 is here.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u31-oth-JPR

Choose the one appropriate for your environment.